# phpBB Error - PHP Warning

Tags: php, shared-hosting, phpbb, phpbb3

I have one phpBB forum on a shared hosting provider, and i get this error

```
[phpBB Debug] PHP Warning: in file [ROOT]/includes/auth/CAS/CAS/Client.php on line 905: session_start(): open(/hermes/phpsessions/S/T/-/Z/sess_ST-ZhPr8mYrwe, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2)
[phpBB Debug] PHP Warning: in file [ROOT]/includes/auth/CAS/CAS/Client.php on line 905: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at [ROOT]/includes/functions.php:3906)
[phpBB Debug] PHP Warning: in file [ROOT]/includes/auth/CAS/CAS/Client.php on line 1614: session_write_close(): open(/hermes/phpsessions/S/T/-/Z/sess_ST-ZhPr8mYrwe, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2)
[phpBB Debug] PHP Warning: in file [ROOT]/includes/auth/CAS/CAS/Client.php on line 1614: session_write_close(): Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (4;/hermes/phpsessions)
[phpBB Debug] PHP Warning: in file [ROOT]/includes/auth/CAS/CAS/Client.php on line 1618: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at [ROOT]/includes/functions.php:3906)
```

the strange thing here, is that happened unexpectedly one day, it used to be working correctly. Also in my private directories i don't have any `/hermes`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that session directory is writable or you can set a path yourself with:

```
session_save_path
```

[This comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php#98106) is also useful if you are using above function.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but can you give me some extra details ? in phpbb config i cannot find such a parameter, and cause it is shared hosting i cannot configure php itself.

Comment: You may want to contact your host, it may be a PHP configuration error - the session path directory is not writable. You can change it, though in your phpBB config file by using session_save_path